# image uploading issue in cordova ionic from gallery. Selection cancelled error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working in a sample application of image uploading using ionic cordova library on android platform. When i first install the application, image is uploaded fine. After that, it shows error "selection cancelled". Can anyone help me when this error will occur and why.

```js
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
var image = document.getElementById('tempImage');
console.log("images : ");
console.log(image);
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

    //console.log(imageData);
    //console.log(options);
    var image = document.getElementById('tempImage');
    image.src = imageData;

    var server = "http://yourdomain.com/upload.php",
        filePath = imageData;

    var date = new Date();

    var options = {
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "image/jpg"
    };

    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath, options).then(function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
        console.log('Result_' + result.response[0] + '_ending');
        alert("success");
        alert(JSON.stringify(result.response));

    }, function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }, function (progress) {
        // constant progress updates
    });


}, function(err) {
    // error
    alert(err);
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Please let me know the reasons as why the error always occured "selection cancelled". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to me. I was able to solve this by myself. It's a bad from my end as i have used input type file in view section. So it's throwing the error "selection cancelled". Instead use a button to call the function to open the image gallery section and the rest was working fine at my end. Hope this answer will help someone else.